# Why the Calendar field will auto increase when invoke findById() every time

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I use spring-boot 2.1.7.release and mysql 5.6 coding, some error occured。 The process as Blow:

First, I saved one entity to database。The entity has one field named `applyTime` and the type is `Calendar`
Then, call `findById()`。
Finally, The applyTime will auto increased by some number。

example: The save value's timeInMillis is 2000000L，and the `findById()` return value's timeInMillis is 70400000。

And when update other field to the entity ,the Calendar field will persisted with the new value.

I have created a dome with sample two classes, which is Student and StudentRepository。And the error also appeared。

Entity

```java
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Calendar applyTime;

    // setter and getter ...
}
```

DAO

```java
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

TEST

```java
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Student student = new Student();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        long time = 20000000L;
        /** init with 20,000,000 */
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        student.setApplyTime(calendar);

        /** save entity with: 20,000,000 (1970/1/1 13:33:20 +8:00). database: 1970-01-01 13:33:20 +8:00 */
        studentRepository.save(student);

        Student student1 = studentRepository.findById(student.getId()).get();
        Assertions.assertThat(student1.getApplyTime().getTimeInMillis()).isGreaterThan(time);

        /** get 70400000 (1970/1/2 3:33:20 +8:00) , database:  1970-01-01 13:33:20 (+8:00)*/
        time = student1.getApplyTime().getTimeInMillis();
        logger.warn(String.valueOf(time));

        student1.setName("hi");
        studentRepository.save(student1);

        student1 = studentRepository.findById(student.getId()).get();
        Assertions.assertThat(student1.getApplyTime().getTimeInMillis()).isGreaterThan(time);
        time = student1.getApplyTime().getTimeInMillis();

        /** get  120800000(1970/1/2 17:33:20 +8:00), database: 1970-01-02 03:33:20  you may get other auto increase value*/
        logger.warn(String.valueOf(time));

        student1.setName("hello");
        studentRepository.save(student1);

        student1 = studentRepository.findById(student.getId()).get();
        Assertions.assertThat(student1.getApplyTime().getTimeInMillis()).isGreaterThan(time);
        time = student1.getApplyTime().getTimeInMillis();

        /** get 171200000(1970/1/3 7:33:20 +8:00) database: 1970-01-02 17:33:20 +8:00*/
        logger.warn(String.valueOf(time));
    }
```

mysql

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: example
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3316:3306
```

pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.yml

```
# 测试环境
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    show-sql: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3316/example?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: example
    separator: //

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE
debug: false
```

github: https://github.com/mengyunzhi/jpa-calendar-error

How can I disable the auto increase Calendar field? Thank you!

Comment: Just a thought, I would rather use _LocalDateTime/LocalDate_  instead of _Calendar_

Comment: I would try . But it's a production with spring-boot1.5.3, I am trying update to 2.1.7 now. So some field type changed will effected the api.

Answer (score 0):

When you define one of your fields as Calendar type you have annotate it accordingly to prevent any inconsistencies:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar applyTime;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar applyTime;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have try the two annotate. `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` will set the field value to start of the day, and I need the time stamp. `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` will auto increased also.